# How to enable https in Google Endpoints

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-kubernetes-engine

I am using Google Endpoints ( https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/ ) deployed with OpenAPI definition, ESP on GKE. My api url is something like: `http://appname.endpoints.bgl-preproduction.cloud.goog/`.

I would like to enable https there. Currently when hitting it with `https` I am getting timeouts. Do I need my own certificate even when using `.cloud.goog` domain?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to follow this [instruction](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/enabling-ssl).